# How do I convert a SOAP Envelop into JSON?

Tags: rest, http, soap, dhc

I'm trying to convert this SOAP Envelop into a http POST Request to send via [DHC Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en) (or any other engine).

### Soap Envelop

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xx="http://xx.webservice.company.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xx:MyMethodName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <firstParameter>xx</firstParameter>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <secondParameter>zz</secondParameter>
      </xx:MyMethodName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### DHC Implementation

[image]

I'm getting 200 OK but the response is empty.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we can get a result from a `GET` request, it's not possible to `POST` a `JSON` request if your server is using `SOAP` architecture from behind.

The solution is to `POST` a `SOAP` envelop using XML and the following header parameters:

> **Content-Type** : text/xml; charset=utf-8
>
> **SOAPAction** : (empty)